QGIS problem creating a layer with just road intersections
I have imported a road network from OSM into QSIM. What I now need is a layer of just road intersections. To clean up the road layer I used the processing toolbox and to 'dissolve all', then took that layer and applied 'multipart to singleparts', then used 'line intersections' finally I used 'delete duplicate geometries'. The final layer is:

As can be seen all the road intersections now have a node but so too do some of the roads where there isn't an intersection. I suspect this is because the road is comprised of multiple segments but I had hoped the dissolve etc would have solved that.
Any help would be appreciated.
Kevin

I think I've solved it. I used the wrong 'dissolve'. I had first used dissolve from within GDAL / vector geoprocessing. When I used instead dissolve from vector geometry it seems to work.
